# Variance of two subsamples versus variance of one equivalent big sample

Tags: probability, statistics

I search to calculate the variance of two samplings (with different sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ so $n_1<n_2$) in a multinomial with at least 3 states with probabilities $p_a$,$p_b$ and $p_c$, compared to the variance of one sample of size $N=n_1+n_2$. My question to formalize that are: 1/ should those variances be equal? 2/ if not, is there an analytical form of the 'bias' introduced by two subsamples against on big sampling?

I have an education in maths but not sufficient to tackle this (probably) basic question by myself. Thanks for your pedagogic help.

Answer (score 1):

The (unbiaised) sample variance estimators will have the same expectation, which is equal to the true variance of the population. But the smaller the $n$, the larger the dispersion on these. (The variance estimators are themselves random variables.)

Comment: thanks! so if I understand well the main effects will be to spread the variance of the variance expectation? Can this variance being formulated in a simple expression?

Comment: @sol: no, the variance of the variance. The variance expectation is not a random variable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance